# find() using overloaded operator==

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overload-resolution, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

I try to find an element in a vector using overloaded operator==(). However, if using `type1` in the following code, the output is 1 and 0 (not found). Using `type2` gives both 1 and 1. The environment is Xubuntu 12.04 and g++ version 4.6.3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<string, int> type1;
struct type2: public type1 {};
#define TYPE type1

bool operator== (const TYPE& lhs, const TYPE& rhs) {
    return lhs.first == rhs.first;
}

int main()
{
    vector<TYPE> vec;
    TYPE v1, v2;

    v1.first = "abc"; v1.second = 1; vec.push_back(v1);
    v2.first = "abc"; v2.second = 2;

    cout << (v1 == v2) << endl;
    cout << (find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), v2) != vec.end()) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer by @AlexanderGessler is incomplete in several details. So let's play compiler for both expressions and both types, shall we?

### Expression 1

`cout << (v1 == v2) << endl;`

First, for both `type1` and `type2`, **unqualified name lookup** starts at the `main()` function scope outwards, and finds your own `operator==` function at the global scope.

Second, **argument-dependent name lookup** (ADL) finds the function template `operator==` for `std::pair` from `namespace std`. Actually, ADL finds many more `std::operator==` function templates (those from `std::vector` and `std::string`, since you included those headers as well).

**Note**: ADL also finds a match for `type2`, because its base class `type1` will add `namespace std` to the set of its associated namespaces.

---

**3.4.2 Argument-dependent name lookup [basic.lookup.argdep]**

> — If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are:
>   the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its
>   direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces are the
>   namespaces of which its associated classes are members.

---

Third, **template argument deduction** takes place for all found function templates. For `type1`, only the function template for `std::pair` will survive argument deduction (and it deduces its template arguments to be `std::string`  and `int`, respectively). However, for `type2`, there is no set of template arguments that will fit because `type2` is not an instantiation of a `std::pair` template.

Fourth, **overload resolution** comes into play. For `type1`, both your own function `operator==` and the `std::operator==` function template are of equal rank (Exact Match). Therefore the tie-break will select your non-template function. For `type2`, there is only one viable function so overload resolution does not come into play and your function will be selected.

**Conclusion 1**: `type1` and `type2` will give the same answer (your version is selected), albeit for different reasons.

### Expression 2

`cout << (find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), v2) != vec.end()) << endl;`

Here we need to first resolve the call to `find`. Because of your `using namespace std;`, unqualified name lookup already finds (no pun intended) `std::find`, but even without the using directive, ADL on the `std::vector` iterator would have found it. It will deduce the third template argument for `std::find` to either `type1` or `type2`.

Within `std::find`, a call to `operator==` is found. Again, ordinary lookup will be performed first. However, this takes place from within `namespace std`. It will find several `operator==` function templates (for `std::vector`, `std::string` and `std::pair`). As soon as candidates in one scope are found during unqualified name lookup, this phase of name lookup stops.

However, ADL is still being performed. Note though that the global namespace is not an associated namespace to `type1` **because it is only a typedef** to a class in `namespace std`. So for `type1`, ADL does not find anything new. In contrast, `type2` does have the global namespace as its associated namespace and so ADL will find your `operator==` function template in that case.

For `type1`, template-argument-deduction finds `std::string` and `int` as template arguments for the `operator==` function template for `std::pair`. For `type2`, there is again no set of template arguments that will fit because `type2` is not an instantiation of a `std::pair` template.

That leaves overload resolution. For `type1`, there is only one viable function (the instance of the `std::operator==` template), and overloads resolution does not come into play. For `type2`, there is also only one viable function (viable because it only requires a standard `derived-to-base` conversion). Hence overload resolution also does not come into play.

**Conclusion 2**: for `type1` (`std` version) and `type2` (your version) you get different results.

### Summary

Just because these things can get very tricky with multiple overloads in different namespaces, here's a summary table with the holy trinity (name lookup, argument deduction and overload resolution). For each phase, and for each type, I have listed the surviving candidates after that phase. The bottom row shows the called function.

**Expression 1**

```
+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| phase               | type1           | type2           |
+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| unqualified lookup  |    ::operator== |    ::operator== |
| ADL                 | std::operator== | std::operator== |
+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| argument deduction  |    ::operator== |    ::operator== |
|                     | std::operator== |                 |
+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| overload resolution |    ::operator== |    ::operator== |
+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

**Expression 2**

```
+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| phase               | type1           | type2           |
+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| unqualified lookup  | std::operator== | std::operator== |
| ADL                 |                 |    ::operator== |
+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| argument deduction  | std::operator== |    ::operator== |
+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| overload resolution | std::operator== |    ::operator== |
+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Note that unqualified lookup finds a different name depending on the scope it starts in (function scope inside global scope versus namespace scope), and that ADL similarly finds a different name depending on which namespace is considered associated (`namespace std` vs the global namespace).

Comment: Took some time to understand. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 8):

`std::pair` has its default `operator==` in namespace `std`, which is a template for arbitrary pairs, comparing both the `first` and the `second` fields. This operator gets picked in one of the four cases, namely `find` with `TYPE == type1`. The details are a bit complicated though:

What actually happens for `TYPE == type1` is (correct me if I'm wrong)

- for `v1 == v2` ADL (*Argument Dependent Name Lookup*) is applied to find the `operator==` in `std`, meaning this operator is added to the normal overload set. However, the non-template version in the current translation unit is still preferred against the template `operator==` from `std`.
- The `std::find` call is instanced within `std`, thus lookup for `operator==` starts directly in `std`. It finds one match (without using ADL!) and therefore does not search the enclosing scope which would have contained the OP's own operator.

And for `TYPE == type2`

- `v1 == v2` is easy -it directly finds the `operator==` in the enclosing namespace.
- `std::find` is also instanced in `std`, but the custom operator from the main scope is added to the overload resolution set using ADL and then found to be more specific than the one in `std`.

Comment: Good point about the namespace. But is it the namespace of `pair` or `find` that matters most?

Comment: As far as I know `find` is instanced in the current translation unit and the `operator==` is then resolved using ADL on `std::pair`.

Comment: @Nawaz, then why does `v1 == v2` return `true` in both cases?

Comment: @MarkRansom: You're right. I'm a bit confused. And I don't think this answer explains the behavior, so I removed my upvote and then downvoted for being incomplete.

Comment: Good point - a possible starting point could be that `operator==` finds the normal `std::pair` operator via ADL, but still takes the new one because non-templates are preferred to non-templates. Still does not explain via the `find` version fails.

Comment: Ok, in the `std::find` version it does not use ADL and therefore stops at the namespace `std`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I think overload resolution comes into picture. When calling from global namespace, the overload with `std::pair<std::string,int>` as parameter type is a **better match** than the overload (which is template) defined in `std::` namespace.

Comment: Edited, I think this is better now.

Comment: I think it is indeed better now. Removed downvote and then upvoted :D

Comment: Edited, now it should be complete.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations from all. It was my first post here. Thanks again for the accurate and quick reply.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to downvote it. You missed several details that I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`std::pair` has its own [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) that takes precedence over your own.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off using [find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead of find. It takes a predicate, so you can just define your comparer as an ordinary function/functor and pass it.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to use functor as predicate.